# Как составить SQL запрос с выводом строк по длине числового значения?

Tags: sql

Необходим запрос, который будет выводить строки в зависимости от длины числового значения. Попробовал

```
select * from dict where lenght(localrplversion) > 8;
```

Получаю ошибку ERROR: function lenght(numeric) does not exist
Попробовал изменить тип

```
select * from dict where lenght(cast(localrplversion as VARCHAR)) > 8;
```

Получил ERROR: function lenght(character varying) does not exist

Comment: А тупо десятичный логарифм посчитать не судьба?

Comment: lenght -> length

Comment: Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия?

Comment: Попробуйте  len(localrplversion) > 8 либо len(cast(localrplversion as VARCHAR(100))) (Sybase)